# Where does Gradle look for buildscript dependencies when there are no repositories configured?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to understand how the `buildscript {}` block works in Gradle.

I've understood that the `repositories {}` block inside of it should be used when referencing external plugins:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
```

But I don't understand where Gradle looks for dependencies when there is no `repositories {}` block inside the `buildscript {}` block. If I remove it from the above example, I am still able to build my project without errors:

```groovy
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
```

Shouldn't Gradle throw an error in this case?

Here is my full `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

group 'it.foo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

I am running this Gradle file with Gradle 7.1.1, but I had the same behaviour with Gradle 6.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

It does throw an error...

Using exactly your example above with Gradle 7.1 you get

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'norepo'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Comment: I've added to my question the full `build.gradle` file. I have also upgraded to Gradle 7.1.1, but I am still able to run that file without errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Gradle implicitly includes `gradlePluginPortal()` in `buildscript.repositories`.

`gradlePluginPortal()` evaluates to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2.

You can confirm this by changing

```
com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5
```

in your `build.gradle` to, e.g.

```
com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.999
```

and notice that Gradle's error message says that it searched in https://plugins.gradle.org/m2 despite not having that explicitly in your `buildscript.repositories`.